# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface, Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I have many `CSV` files, and I want to them join then into one `txt` file, `binary` format..
The following code give the above error:

```
import os
from csv import reader
from csv import writer

CONST_DATA_DIR = "F:/Data/"
CONST_DATABIN_DIR = "F:/DataBinary/"


def createFilesArr():
    filesArr = []
    os.chdir(CONST_DATA_DIR)
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            filesArr.append(file)
    return filesArr


filesArr = createFilesArr()

newFileName = "oneBinaryFile.txt"
newFile = open(CONST_DATABIN_DIR + newFileName, 'wb')

for file in filesArr:
    currentFile = open(CONST_DATA_DIR + file, 'r', newline='', encoding='UTF8')
    newFile.write(currentFile.read())
    currentFile.close()

newFile.close()
```

**EDIT:**
The `CSV` files are originally written as a `txt` type. In the other hand the merge file should be in the binary format.
The process of creating the `CSV` file is complicated, hence, if possible, I prefer to somehow convert the files before reading.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python distinguishes between binary and text I/O.

```
newFile = open(CONST_DATABIN_DIR + newFileName, 'wb')
```

Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument) return contents as bytes objects without any decoding.

```
currentFile = open(CONST_DATA_DIR + file, 'r', newline='', encoding='UTF8')
newFile.write(currentFile.read())
```

In text mode (the default, or when 't' is included in the mode argument), the contents of the file are returned as str, the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified encoding if given.

All streams are careful about the type of data you give to them. For example giving a `str` object to the `write()` method of a binary stream will raise a `TypeError`. So will giving a bytes object to the write() method of a text stream.

Comment: The question was been editted. Thanks for the current answer.